# How can I return focus to DIV ID not an INPUT name within form

Tags: javascript, html

I am wanting to check if a radio button is not checked...my java checks the field and if blank will return the user to the "YES" value of the input...I am wanting to return the user to the div id="q10a"...the reason is when the user is returned to the radio button the question is cut off due to page length...so I want the focus to be put on the div id="q10a" (which will help me show question and radio buttons)...

Is there a way of doing this???  below is the HTML code and the Java...thank you in advance for your help...

```
    <div id="q10a" class="quesitonnaire_font_size">
<strong>1. ARE YOU AT LEAST 50 YEARS OF AGE?</strong>
<br>
<br>
<div class="yes_no">
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="q1" VALUE="YES" style="margin-left:-15px">Yes
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="q1" VALUE="NO" style="margin-left:15px">No
</div>
</div>
```

Java checking if input is blank

```
radioOption = -1;
        for (counter=0; counter<q1.length; counter++)
        {
            if (q1[counter].checked) radioOption = counter;
        }

        if (radioOption == -1)
        {
            alert("YOU DID NOT ANSWER QUESTION 1: ARE YOU AT LEAST 50 YEARS OF AGE?");
            Form.q1[0].focus();
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: I.. didn't... quite... understand it :\ I'm sorry..

Comment: I am wanting the focus to be placed on the div id not the input name...

Answer (score 1):

Try using:
`document.getElementById("q10a").focus();` instead of `Form.q1[0].focus();`

Comment: Thank you...I tried above suggestion...the alert will fire, however the focus is null...nothing happens after the alert box is checked...any other ideas???

Comment: What do you mean the focus is null?

Comment: I click the submit button...the alert pop up is triggered...when the alert is acknowledged nothing else happens...it used to take the user back to the question they left blank...know it doesn't do anything after the alert is acknowledged...